# Angular 2: How to set default value of field from parent component back to child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular2-forms

I have the following scenario: childComponent is an angular material slide toggle that is used in different parts of my application. It is used in parentComponent1 and parentComponent2. In parentComponent1 I want to set the default value of the slide toggle to be `true` but in parentComponent2 I want it to be `false`. How do I go about setting the default value of the slide toggle in the parentComponents?

I've tried the usual @Input recipe outlined in the angular docs (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding), but no success.

Snippet of my child component:

```
<mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="toggleFilterText"
      class="example-margin"
      [color]="color"
      [(ngModel)]="checked"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (change)="onToggleFilterChange(checked)">
      {{toggleFilterText}}
```

and child ts

```
@Input()
checked: boolean;
```

What do I do in my parent ts files to set the default value? Thanks.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, `@Input` is absolutely available in Angular 2+

Comment: Don't know where my brain was. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your parent components are set-up and if they are the same component.

If they are different components:

`parent-component-1.ts`:

```
public class Parent1Component {
    public checked: boolean;
    constructor() {
        checked = true;
    }
}
```

`parent-component-2.ts`:

```
public class Parent2Component {
    public checked: boolean;
    constructor() {
        checked = false;
    }
}
```

If they are the same component, you would need to do something like the following:

`parent-component.ts`:

```
public class ParentComponent {
    @Input()
    checked: boolean;
}
```

HTML:

```
<parent-component [checked]="true"></parent-component><!-- First -->
<parent-component [checked]="false"></parent-component><!-- Second -->
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the delayed response!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you need the value of 'checked' to be set. Add the input parameter to your HTML tag and set it to the desired value

```
<mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="toggleFilterText"
      [checked] = "false"
      class="example-margin"
      [color]="color"
      [(ngModel)]="checked"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (change)="onToggleFilterChange(checked)" / >
```